# proxy server configuration using NetworkManager nmcli

Tags: proxy, networkmanager

I need to set proxy server URL on my machine with NetworkManager commands only. I can't install other tools. The device runs MbedLinux (linux embedded distro).

Q: How do I configure the proxy server using NetworkManager nmcli commands?

I found [these NetworkManager proxy settings](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-proxy.html), but I have no idea how to set these settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit a network configuration with the command:

```
nmcli con edit NETWORK_NAME
```

Then you can change the network proxy settings by running:

```
set proxy.method VALUE
```

or

```
set proxy.pac-script VALUE
```

You can see all settings available by running `print`

About the settings in the link you posted it appears that you have to provide for nmcli the path where a PAC file is located or an url so it can find the settings for you proxy. You can find more info about PAC files in here:
http://findproxyforurl.com/example-pac-file/

To be true I've never tried but it seems easy to just create the file and setting it's path on the connection settings.